# Is password-less access to SSH using chroot setup possible?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, sshd, chroot

I was able to log in into a ssh server using public and private keys without using a password.

I was able to also setup chroot and jail a new user and avoid that the user could connect via ssh but could access sftp using this very helpful article:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/

The problem now is that I can't combine the two, when I want to log in with the user that has the private and public keys (which I tried to log in with the RequirePassword in sshd_config file configuration on) it was working just fine but when I turn that rule off I'm not able to connect anymore.

The error that I get is:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
Connection closed
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible, where have you placed the keys on the server?  Are you sure you have given the keys and containing directories the proper permissions?

Comment: you should be able to distinguish rules for both users with "Match" directives. Can you give additional detail on configuration in sshd_config ?

Comment: @Zoredache: Yes, in fact I used ssh-copy-id to make sure about that.

Comment: @tonioc: The only line that I changed from that configuration file is PasswordRequired to no

Comment: About the only thing I can really suggest is that you set your client in verbose mode and watch for errors.  If you don't find any, then adjust your SSH server to run in verbose mode and watch for errors related to your loging.